# Why is my method called by Unity when I don't call it in code?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, structure

I can not understand why the method `OnDrawGizmos()` executes while it is not called in both the `Start()` method and `Update()` method, but it is executed when I run the Unity project.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Transform grounder;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnDrawGizmos(){
        Gizmos.color = Color.white;
        Gizmos.DrawSphere (grounder.position, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As the name suggests, `OnDrawGizmozs` gets called by the unity engine. It's a message function that gets called on classes that implement MonoBehaviour. Excert from the documentation:

> ## Description
>
> Implement OnDrawGizmos if you want to draw gizmos that are also
> pickable and always drawn.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDrawGizmos.html

This means you don't need to call the function yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's called by Unity on classes that implement MonoBehaviour, according to the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html).